# Wirelessly adding an intermediate switch into a conventional 2 way wiring system

Tags: wiring

I have at home a normal conventional 2 way switching electrical wiring for a lamp

[image]

I want to have 3 switches to control the lamp, using an intermediate switch on a certain spot, though such third spot has no wiring access.

[image]

How can I wirelessly and intermediately switch that lamp? That is, I don't need any specific market product; I want to solve the problem of **wirelessly adding an intermediate switch into a conventional 2 way wiring system**.

Comment: I edited my question. I don't need any specific market product; I want to solve the problem of **wirelessly adding an intermediate switch into a conventional 2 way wiring system**.

Comment: How about a programmable Bluetooth low energy or Zigbee module, running from a battery, driving an appropriately rated *latching* SPDT relay? Beware lamps with high inrush current, they could cook your relay contacts.

Comment: @amb btw, I'm newby here, why my question is no hold?

Comment: @Dave Tweed , why my question is still on-hold if I already amended it accordingly?

Comment: Are you now asking us to design a wirelessly-controlled 4-way switch (DPDT relay) for you? That would make the question too broad. You really should take the site tour and find out what is and is not on-topic before posting.

Comment: This sounds very much like a home improvement question, perhaps it should be asked there.

Comment: easy solution: replace one of the end switchies with a remote-controlled switch.

Comment: @Jasen , I want to have three switches

Comment: @Dave Tweed , either is a market product or too broad.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira, you want three controls. you could add a manual 3 way beside the remote control switch receiver.

Comment: @Jasen could you kindly suggest me any product on the market with a link?